# Button click in html and php isn't responding

Tags: php, html

This is the button `<button type='submit' name="myBtn" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary ml-5">Match</button>`

And this is the part in PHP which should be triggered

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['myBtn']))
    {
        echo "in";
        $q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM members1 WHERE name='$username'");
        $conv=$q->fetch_assoc();
        $id=(int)$conv['id'];
        $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM interests WHERE perId='$id'");
        $row=mysqli_num_rows($res);
        $c=0;
        foreach ($_GET['interests'] as $selectedOption)
            $c=$c+1;
        $result=($c/$row)*100;
        echo $result;
    }
?>
```

Also, i would be grateful if someone would tell me how to convert the id I'm recieving in $q to integer. I don't think what i did is correct.

Beginner here, Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the button in a form? Also - as a beginner make it easy on yourself and learn about `stored procedures` now before proceeding with poor practises ( embedding variables directly in the SQL makes it vulnerable to sql injection )

Comment: Also - you can use a single query with a join rather than these tow separate queries

Comment: @RamRaider No it's not in a form, and I am using it as a trigger for a dialogue box in javascript later too. Thanks for the advice I will read up on Stored procedures. Yeah, I just realized maybe I could've used join instead of two queries.